# How to make this recursive relationship nonrecursive?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, computational-geometry, recurrence-relation

I need to make a recursive relationship for a function `f(m, n)` nonrecursive to make it more efficient and succinct in my code.

I stumbled across an important recurrence relationship dealing with the number of vertices, edges, faces, and solids ([m-polytopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope)) in an n-cube which is based off of a simpler algorithm for an n-simplex which uses Pascal's triangle:

For a simplex:
nCm gives you the number of m-polytopes (m = 1 for points, 2 for lines, 3 for faces) in an n-simplex (1-simplex is a line, 2-simplex is a triangle, 3-simplex is a tetrahedron).

The pattern between the n-simplex m-polytopes and the n-cube m-polytopes are very similar:

```
Here is the n-cube up to 10
10-polytopes:                                                            
9-polytopes:                                                           1
8-polytopes:                                                     1    16
7-polytopes:                                               1    14   112
6-polytopes:                                         1    12    84   448
5-polytopes:                                   1    10    60   280  1120
4-polytopes:                             1     8    40   160   560  1792
3-polytopes:                       1     6    24    80   240   672  1792
2-polytopes:                 1     4    12    32    80   192   448  1024
1-polytopes:           1     2     4     8    16    32    64   128   256
Here is the n-simplex up to 10
10-polytopes:                                                            
9-polytopes:                                                           1
8-polytopes:                                                     1     9
7-polytopes:                                               1     8    36
6-polytopes:                                         1     7    28    84
5-polytopes:                                   1     6    21    56   126
4-polytopes:                             1     5    15    35    70   126
3-polytopes:                       1     4    10    20    35    56    84
2-polytopes:                 1     3     6    10    15    21    28    36
1-polytopes:     1     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

And here is the c code that generated that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TOP 10

// nothing to see here
int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
// a recursive implementation for the number of 
// m-polytopes in an n-cube
int ncubeRecursive(int n, int m)
{
    if (n == 0 && m == 0)
        return 1;
    else if(n < 0 || m < 0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        return (ncubeRecursive(n - 1, m - 1) + 2 * ncubeRecursive(n - 1, m));
    }
}
// missing a nonrecursive algorithm
// YOUR JOB TO FIX THIS


// a recursive implementation for the number of
// m-polytopes in an n-simplex
int nsimplexRecursive(int n, int m)
{
    if (n == 0 && m == 0)
        return 1;
    else if(n < 0 || m < 0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        return (nsimplexRecursive(n - 1, m - 1) + nsimplexRecursive(n - 1, m));
    }
}
// a nonrecursive algorithm
int nsimplexNonrecursive(int n, int m)
{
    return factorial(n)/(factorial(n - m) * factorial(m));
}

int main()
{
    printf("Here is the n-cube up to %i\n", TOP);
    for (int n = TOP; n > 0; --n)
    {
        printf("%i-polytopes:", n);
        for (int m = 0; m < TOP; ++m)
        {
            int val = ncubeRecursive(m, n);
            if (val == 0)
                printf("%6c", ' ');
            else
                printf("%6i", val);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Here is the n-simplex up to %i\n", TOP);
    for (int n = TOP; n > 0; --n)
    {
        printf("%i-polytopes:", n);
        for (int m = 0; m < TOP; ++m)
        {
            int val = nsimplexNonrecursive(m, n);
            if (val == 0)
                printf("%6c", ' ');
            else
                printf("%6i", val);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone here see a non-recursive pattern? I just don't know how to analyze a recursive relationship like this for a function that takes to inputs like `f(m, n)` instead of just `f(x)`.

Comment: Please replace your code with pseudocode, or even better, with the recurrence relation that you're interested in. Without reading the program it's hard to tell what $f(m,n)$ even is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the $n$-cube, you are interested in [A013609](https://oeis.org/A013609) (see the link), in which the following explicit formula is given:
$$ f(m,n) = \binom{m}{n} 2^n. $$
(Your indexing could be slightly different.)

Tip: Whenever you have a recurrence relation and looking for a closed form, calculate a few entries and look it up in the OEIS. That's how I found the formula.

For the $n$-simplex, as you mention, this is just Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Nice man, that is a really useful thing.